# Use label value as the value for timer interval

Tags: vb.net, timer, label, intervals

In visual basic .net is it possible to use the label1.text as the value for timer1.interval?

I've tried the following, unfortunately it isn't working.

```
Dim Try_Interval As Integer = My.Settings.Error_Millisec
Int32.TryParse(frmSettings.Lbl_Error_Millisec_Fin.Text, Try_Interval)
```

It says

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Value '0' is not a valid value for Interval.
>   Interval must be greater than 0.

I've also tried to store it in the my.settings like the below code

```
Dim Try_Max As Integer = Convert.ToDouble(My.Settings.Error_Try)
Dim Try_Interval As Integer = My.Settings.Error_Millisec
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Int32.TryParse` initializes the int parameter when it could parse the string to `Int32` successfully, otherwise it will be 0. So the root issue is that the string cannot be parsed. What is it's value?

Comment: The value frmSettings.Lbl_Error_Millisec_Fin.Text is 100, take note that I've taken that from another form.

Comment: So first you comment that it's 0, then - after i'be posted the answer - you delete that comment and say it's 100? What is it now? Is the issue fixed?

Comment: Sorry, I mistype 100 to 0, I didn't mean it. Yeah, it is still not working Sir.

Comment: Strange because the error message really suggests that it's 0, you get it when then value is <=0. Have you used the debugger to see the real value? Maybe it's `" 100"`(trailing space) which causes the `Int.TryParse` to return 0. Then use `frmSettings.Lbl_Error_Millisec_Fin.Text.Trim()`

Comment: I'll check the process from the start Sir. Yeah, I think you are correct, maybe it accidentally changes the value to 0. I'll tell you the result later. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int32.TryParse` initializes the int parameter when it could parse the string to `Int32` successfully, otherwise it will be 0. So either the string cannot be parsed because the format is invalid orit is `"0"`. What is it's value?

> The value frmSettings.Lbl_Error_Millisec_Fin.Text is 0, take note that
>   I've taken that from another form.

[`Timer.Interval` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

> An Int32 specifying the number of milliseconds before the Tick event
>   is raised relative to the last occurrence of the Tick event. The value
>   **cannot be less than one**.

So specify a value that is `>= 1`.

Comment: I do a simple project with a timer, and a textbox. When the button is clicked it will trigger this code `Dim interval_1 As Integer
        Int32.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, interval_1)
        TextBox3.Text = interval_1` unfortunately the result is 0. Any suggestion Sir?

Comment: Done Sir, yeah. Your suggestion is right, the problem is in my other code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the interval set as follows:

```
    Dim timerValue As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(timerLabel.Text, timerValue)
    Timer1.Interval = timerValue
```